# Change VSO account region/location

Tags: azure-devops

early on during the setup of my VSO account, i either missed the region setup field or probably ended up with the default, which turned out to be South Central US.

i would like to change that field to West US. however, when i go to the named VSO account (https://username.visualstudio.com)>Control panel>Settings>Region, there does not seem to be a way to make the change.

in Azure, the Region information is displayed under the column titled "Location" and all other Azure services i use are configured as West US.

how do i change the Region/Location setting for my named account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last I saw (mentioned in here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/10/28/visual-studio-online-is-in-europe.aspx) this not currently possible but is planned for the future. Blog does say it is possible for support to move to a different region but it looks like they will judge on a case by case request.

Comment: you are correct. the option is not yet available according to three sources.

1. the visual studio user voice:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6633664-change-visual-studio-online-account-region#comments

2. the azure cloud services location chart:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

3. when i tried to open a new VSO account, the West US region is not available: [Australia East, South Central US, West Europe]. 

in the mean time, i voted to add the option (#1 above).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such self-service to change region in VSTS "Settings" page. But according to [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/6633664-change-visual-studio-team-services-account-region) post, there is a official channel to do such change by submitting a service request to Microsoft at(https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/).

VSTS support group will contact account owner based on your request and do the change offline until the mentioned self-service become available online.